# Server Downloading File Instead Of Showing It

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

I have a Apache server running at Rackspace Cloud Hosting, so I've installed Wordpress manually(setting up the database, wget the latest.zip...) and placed it at `/var/www`, but now when I try to access it for the first time, it downloads a strange file with the IP as name instead of showing me the Wordpress Installation.

*PS: The same happens if I place it on a sub-directory like `blog`*

Comment: PHP doesn't seem to be installed / enabled, causing one to download plain files. (Do change all your passwords after you've fixed this issue...)

Comment: If you are using Cloud Sites, it should take care of it for you. Go to the Cloud control panel, go to Hosting > Cloud Sites, choose your site, then Features, you should be able to enabled PHP there.

If you are using Cloud Servers, you will need to manually install, configure and enable PHP.  This process will vary based on what distribution you are running and what package management system you have available.

Comment: On a side note: it's a good practice to set up a MySQL user with only the privileges it needs for a web application, not `root` :P

Comment: @Wrikken oooooh, naughty naughty! :D

Comment: @Nathan: as Wrikken says: every file you've uploaded now is readable to the entire world. Since we know wordpress and know the file which contains your password(s), you might want to remove that file and change all passwords.

Comment: Just changed all the passwords, thanks for the advice @Konerak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you haven't configured Apache to execute PHP (mod_php?) Right now it's just serving your PHP files like any old file type so what you're getting is your wordpress index.php as a file download.

I'm not sure what the process is for Rackspace, but usually this would mean enabling mod_php.

Do you have any other PHP files that work on that site?

Comment: Someone knows how to enable `mod_php` at Rackspace

Comment: @Nathan, I'm sorry is that a question or a statment? If you're asking me, I don't know how to do it in rackspace. If you're running your own VPS I suppose it's the same as in regular linux

Comment: It's a question sorry, I forgot to put the question mark, so sorry

Answer (score 3):

you need to tell Apache to excuate php files. add the following to your Apache configuration file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php
```

make sure PHP module is included in Apache configuration first!